# What type of quick disconnects for 18ga to 12ga low voltage wire connections?

Tags: wiring, low-voltage

I'm powering an 18ga 24V DC submersible pump for a water fountain in the yard using a 110V AC to 24V DC power supply (18 ga).  I'm planning to use 12ga stranded low voltage wire (max.30V) from the power supply to the pump (approx. distance 70ft).  Looking for compatible quick disconnects for 18ga to 12ga at both the power supply location and the pump location. [image]

I purchased the following disconnects but since the connections to the pump will be exposed to the elements, not sure if they will adequately protect against moisture. Wondering if I should look into military grade disconnects to be safe?[image]

Comment: What are you using to house this connection?

Answer (score 2):

I [did a search for waterproof wire connectors](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=waterproof+wire+connectors&t=h_&ia=images&iax=images). Get one that has 2 wires and is a screw-type connector with a good rubber or silicone seal. And make sure the connector fits your size wire.

When in doubt, if there is space where the wire enters the connector, seal with 100% silicone.

Source: I have solar panels that power a water pump outside and I use these light duty connectors which work fine. But I also put the connectors on a brick, off the ground, so they won't get submerged during a heavy rain.

[image: Light connectors]

But these connectors were tricky to put wire into and assemble. I'd use different connectors next time.

You want IP65 or higher rated connectors, IP68 preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I would use insulated spade or disconnect terminals yellow for the 12 awg and red for the 18 awg like mnl10-250fix female yellow for the 12 awg and mng18-250dmix red for the males if both are the same brand they fit tightly together when properly crimped and put together you cannot short these out. I use this same combination changing from our control (nothing smaller than 12 awg) going to sensors that are 18 to 22 awg wires. There are also bullet connectors but those may have different sized connectors. The 250 is the standard 1/4” male and female in the spade or disconnect terminals. These are used in automotive and boating all the time.

Comment: Thanks Ed!  This is what I was looking for.  Now I just need to find a retailer that sells individual connectors as I don't need bulk quantity!  Would an electrical supply retailer stock these items?  BTW, the connections to the power supply will be out of the weather, however, I'm unsure if the connections to the pump will be totally free of moisture, as the pump will be located within a "disappearing fountain" plastic basin set at ground level in the yard.  Are these spade connectors rated as waterproof?

Comment: Auto parts stores carry them in maybe in 5 packs I mentioned the colors because those relate to size , most are 1/4 inch but there are some smaller ones. If you can’t find the insulated ones electrical tape will work.